# How do I make haskell-mode package work with Emacs on Nixos?

Tags: emacs, haskell-mode, nixos, nix

I am using `configuration.nix` to install both `emacs` and `haskellMode` package in a way:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self : [
     self.cabalInstall
     self.happy
     self.alex
     self.ghcMod
  ]))
  emacs
  emacs24Packages.haskellMode
];
```

My `.emacs` file contains:

```
(require 'haskell-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-hi2)
```

Emacs then starts with no errors (so I assume that it can find `haskell-mode`), but it doesn't go to Haskell minor mode when I open `.hs` files.

`~/.nix-profile/share/emacs/site-lisp/haskell-....` files do exist in my profile, if it matters...

So, how do I make it work?

Comment: Can you manually enable the mode with `M-x haskell-mode RET`?

Comment: Hi @Chris , when I do that I have the following error from Emacs:
`Error in post-command-hook (global-font-lock-mode-check-buffers): (void-variable haskell-font-lock-choose-keywords)`. Any idea of what it means?

Comment: Looks like `haskell-mode.el` should provide `haskell-font-lock-choose-keywords`, but it seems to be not defined, so `haskell-mode` has not been loaded for some reason?

Comment: It does look like something didn't get built properly, but unfortunately I've never used NixOS and I'm not sure how `environment.systemPackages` is meant to work. I install virtually everything through `package.el` and MELPA now that it is in widespread use. Perhaps that would give you better results?

Comment: Yes, MELPA worked for me too, I just wanted it to be part of my "declarative configuration" which is a nice Nixos feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same issue trying to use `haskell-indent` instead of `hi2`.
Anyways the output you get by doing `M-x haskell-mode RET` alerts that haskell font-lock is missing.

Solve this by declaring that you `(require 'haskell-font-lock)`.

Then if your `.emacs` file have the following:

```
(require 'haskell-mode) (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-hi2)
```

You should add `(require 'hi2)` as it's pointed [here](https://github.com/nilcons/hi2).

```
(require 'haskell-mode)
(require 'haskell-font-lock)
(require 'hi2)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-hi2)
```

Note that hi2.el is not provided by `haskell-mode` package.

Hope this helps!